# How to query and group every continuous number series in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have this freight.or_nos table which contains series of receipt numbers. I want to list all the or's being issued excluding the status='Cancelled' making the series broken in groups.
For example I have this receipt stab 125001-125050, and 125020 is cancelled so the listing result would be:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  OR Start  |    OR End    |   Quantity   |   Amount   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 125001     | 125019       |           19 |            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 125021     | 125050       |           30 |            |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

This seems to be a tough query.

Comment: im not sure on what you needed but base on what i understood you can use between statement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading but I already made it, just now! :)
Here's my query(disregard the other characters it's form our CGI):

```
{.while SELECT `start`,`end`,or_prefix,or_suffix,SUM(a.amount) AS g_total,COUNT(*) AS qcount FROM (SELECT l.id AS `start`,( SELECT MIN(a.id) AS id FROM ( SELECT a.or_no AS id FROM freight.`or_nos` a WHERE a.status!='Cancelled' AND a.log_user = 0@user_teller AND DATE(a.or_date)='@user_date`DATE'  AND IF(a.status='Default' AND a.amount=0,0,1)  ) AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT a.or_no AS id FROM freight.`or_nos` a WHERE a.status!='Cancelled' AND a.log_user = 0@user_teller AND DATE(a.or_date)='@user_date`DATE'  AND IF(a.status='Default' AND a.amount=0,0,1)    ) AS b ON a.id = b.id - 1 WHERE b.id IS NULL AND a.id >= l.id ) AS `end` FROM ( SELECT a.or_no AS id FROM freight.`or_nos` a WHERE a.status!='Cancelled' AND a.log_user = 0@user_teller AND DATE(a.or_date)='@user_date`DATE' AND IF(a.status='Default' AND a.amount=0,0,1)  ) AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT a.or_no AS id FROM freight.`or_nos` a WHERE a.log_user = 0@user_teller AND DATE(a.or_date)='@user_date`DATE' AND IF(a.status='Default' AND a.amount=0,0,1)  )  AS r ON r.id = l.id - 1 WHERE r.id IS NULL) AS k LEFT JOIN freight.`or_nos` a ON a.`or_no` BETWEEN k.start AND k.end  AND DATE(a.`or_date`)='@user_date`DATE' AND a.log_user =0@user_teller AND IF(a.status='Default' AND a.amount=0,0,1) AND a.status!='Cancelled' GROUP BY `start`}
          {.start}{.x.24.12:end}{.x`p0.40.-5:qcount}{.x`p2.57.-15:g_total}{.asc 255}
{.wend}{.asc 255}
```